# ALTER innoDB table from row to page compression

Tags: innodb, mariadb, compression

My tables have been created with InnoDB row compression (`ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED`). Now I am changing them to page compression. According to the [official documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-page-compression/) of MariaDB, enabling page compression affects newly created tables only.

Thus, I create a replica table and use `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

I wonder if it is possible to `ALTER` a table to change the compression type (from row to page) ?

We can `ALTER` an ordinary table to use page compression using

```
ALTER TABLE t1 PAGE_COMPRESSED=1;
```

My question is about a safe way to remove `ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED` and add `PAGE_COMPRESSED=1`.

Comment: Try it with an explicit `ALGORITHM=COPY`.  Also please report back with disk size comparisons between Row and Page.  And any other metrics you have.  Do you have Snappy?  Do you have "punch hole"?

Comment: @RickJames nice point, I will try it. What does `ALGORITHM=COPY` exactly do? I intend to use the default `zlib` as it is used for my current row compression. Since it is SSD, it naturally benefits from sparse files. Of course, I am practising on HDD too (though it is not very favourable, at least theoretically).

Comment: That option to `ALTER` says to: Create new (empty) table; Copy data into it; Rename to swap.  _Logically_ it involves a "newly create table", but I don't have proof that it achieves your goal.  It _should_ un-row-compress, then page-compress.  Suggest you do OS commands to measure the actual size of the table before and after.  Row compression gives about 2x compression.  Page compression _may_ give you closer to 3x.

Comment: @RickJames I tried your suggestion. `ALGORITHM=COPY` does not help here since it does copy `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` too. Then, there is a conflict between page and row compressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried different methods and read many articles. The standard way to do so is

```
ALTER TABLE t1 KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=0 `PAGE_COMPRESSED`='ON';
```

However, this will leave `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE` on all keys.

Some say this is just the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` display, as `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=8` standards for the largest block size for the keys, but the value is exactly that of the `COMPRESSED` table. If the table was created with `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1`, keys will have `KEY_BLOCK_SIZE=1` after uncompression.

Some, on the other hand, say this bug has been fixed in MySQL 8, but I confirm it exists in MariaDB 10.5.9.

**VERDICT**

`ALTER` is a clean way, but I favour `INSERT INTO SELECT` for two reasons:

1. ALTER writes the uncompressed table on disk while `INSERT` writes the compressed pages on the disk.
2. We can create new table on a separate disk to reduce I/O.